# CorsPolicy error after upgrading to .NET 8

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, .net-8.0

After upgrading to .NET 7 to .NET 8 I am getting below error

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
     {
    
         options.AddPolicy(name: "apiCorsPolicy",
         builder =>
         {           
               builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true);        
               builder.AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");
               builder.AllowAnyMethod();
               builder.AllowCredentials();
       
         });
     });
```

Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://test.cp.in/api/Auth/authenticate' from origin 'https://cp.in' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is that any changes required in .NET 8? Please let me I am  hosted in linux shared
server
EDIT:

```
  if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
      app.UseSwagger();
      app.UseSwaggerUI();
  }
  else
      app.UseHsts();

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseCors("apiCorsPolicy");

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  app.UseCookiePolicy();
  app.MapControllers();
```

Comment: This isn't sufficient to debug and reproduce your issue.  Include the details such as what the preflight OPTIONS request is returning.

Comment: @possum where can i get these details

Comment: Just a possibility... do you configure your app to use the CORS policy, i.e., `app.UseCors("apiCorsPolicy")` somewhere?  If not, you may want to use `AddDefaultPolicy()` instead of `AddPolicy`.

Comment: `SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)` should not be used in conjunction with  `AllowCredentials()`. It's too insecure; see https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties

Comment: @jub0bs I already checked both default also but same issue is it possible issue in shared server nginx config

Comment: The default configuration may not be what you need, but `SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)` is definitely not what you need.

Comment: You can allow multiple origins with `WithOrigins`.

Comment: Could you please share your middelware codes? please make sure the cors middleware is the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Try edit the CORS policy to include '`WithOrigins`' method specifying allowed origins. Modify your CORS policy setup as follows:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("apiCorsPolicy",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://cp.in")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition")
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowCredentials();
        });
});
```

By this way, the CORS policy will include necessary 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response.

Comment: thanks for the anser..but i dont want to WithOrigins("https://cp.in") becuse that api access to angular (web) and also ionic (mbile) application

Comment: i already tested your code in local server..working fine in local when i deploy to shared linux server same issue